# Is there a conflict in these two tensorflow documents about repeat and shuffle?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

## First [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets)

> The tf.data.Dataset.repeat transformation repeats the input data a
>   finite (or infinite) number of times; each repetition of the data is
>   typically referred to as an epoch. The tf.data.Dataset.shuffle
>   transformation randomizes the order of the dataset's examples.
>
> #### Shuffle before repeat
>
> If the shuffle transformation is applied before the repeat
>   transformation, then performance might slow down at
>   the beginning of each epoch related to initialization of the internal
>   state of the shuffle transformation. In other words, the shuffle
>   before repeat provides stronger ordering guarantees.
>
> #### Repeat before shuffle
>
> If the repeat transformation is applied before the shuffle
>   transformation, then the epoch boundaries are blurred. That is,
>   certain elements can be repeated before other elements appear even
>   once. The repeat before shuffle provides better performance,

## Second [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)

> #### Shuffle before repeat
>
> A .shuffle before a .repeat would shuffle items across epoch boundaries (some items will be seen twice before
>   others are seen at all).
>
> #### Repeat before shuffle
>
> A .shuffle after a .batch would shuffle the order of the batches, but not shuffle the items across batches.

## Question

In first document, they claimed if the repeat transformation is applied before the shuffle transformation, then the epoch boundaries are blurred. That is, certain elements can be repeated before other elements appear even once.

But in second document, they claimed a .shuffle before a .repeat would shuffle items across epoch boundaries (some items will be seen twice before others are seen at all).

Is there a conflict in these tow documents?

Comment: You are right. It seems that the second one with `"some items will be seen twice before others are seen at all"` is incorrect. Not clear why they encourage beginners to use `TF2.0-alpha` with such documentation.